# session id passed but not session variables

Tags: php, session

i can see the same session id echo on both pages .  also hello echoed on first page but the second page `session_['hello'];` says undefined variable.  or is if i use isset seems to show ts not being set on second page.

is this a php.ini issue ?

```html
<?php


  if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4.0', '<')) {
        if(session_id() == '') {session_start();}
   } else  {
   }

  echo session_id();
   $_session['hello'] = 'yes';
  echo $_session['hello'];




?>
    <a href="https://192.168.1.183/hello/b.php">gotob /a>



<?php
   session_start();
   if (isset($_SESSION['hello'])){


   echo $_session['hello'];
}
   echo session_id();


?>
```

Comment: `$_session` <= put all those in UPPER case. It's a [**superglobal**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php)

Comment: One small thing, dont forget to close the `</a>` tag. You currently just have `/a>`

Answer (score 2):

*Elaborating on my comment:*

`$_session` <= put all those in UPPER case `$_SESSION`.

It's a [**superglobal**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) and must be in upper case letters.

Plus, you mention:

> *"but the second page session_['hello']; says undefined variable"*

The syntax is `$_SESSION['hello'];`

You should also make sure that `session_start();` is inside all pages using sessions.

*Oh,* and as a sidenote, and as stated in a comment:

```
<a href="https://192.168.1.183/hello/b.php">gotob /a>
```

the `<` is missing from it.

```
<a href="https://192.168.1.183/hello/b.php">gotob</a>
```